# SpriteKit SKEmitterNode Wont Change Size

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

My SKEmitterNode in my game isnt changing size when I call its property particleSize.

```
    let myParticle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")
    myParticle?.particleSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    self.addChild(myParticle!)
```

My Particle still has its large rectangle size. Am I calling the wrong property or what? Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: By default `particleSize` will be the size of your particle texture. For example the _Smoke_ particle texture of `spark.png` is `64x64` so modifying to `100x100` may not have a huge visual impact.

I would suggest you make use of the `Scale` property in the particle editor and adjust your particle visually until you are happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let myScale: CGFloat = 2  //2 = double dimension; 0.5 = half dimension
let myParticle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")
myParticle?.particleScale = myScale
self.addChild(myParticle!)
```